# как заключить повторение в if

Tags: python

хочу заключить повторение в if. как это сделать?
пример:

```
def button_got_pressed():
    print("кнопка была нажата")

if button_got_pressed() 'функция вызвана снова':
    print('НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ')
```

в данном случае, нужно проверять, нажал ли пользователь на кнопку снова (простым языком вызвал функцию повторно, и если это случилось, то... if)

Comment: переведите вопрос на русский, пожалуйста

Comment: Если нарисуете блок-схему, то станет понятно как должен выглядеть код.

Comment: Вопрос совершенно непонятен. Подумайте, как лучше донести до людей суть вашего вопроса.

Comment: вроде как понятно теперь

Comment: До некоторой степени понятно. А функция всё-равно должна вызваться или нужно предотвратить её вызов? В общем, если знать сценарий использования более чётко, то может быть другие варианты кода будут вообще.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, каждый раз, когда возникает необходимость хранить некоторое состояние между вызовами функции, стоит задуматься об использовании классов:

```
class Button:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def got_pressed(self):
        if self.count > 0:
            print('НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ')
        else:
            self.count += 1
            print("кнопка была нажата")


btn = Button()
btn.got_pressed()  # Напечатает: кнопка была нажата
btn.got_pressed()  # Напечатает: НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вариант с дефолтным параметром функции в виде коллекции, такой параметр сохраняет состояние между вызовами:

```
def button_got_pressed(again=[]):
    print("кнопка была нажата")
    if not again:
        again.append('Yes')
        return False
    return True

print('Первый вызов')
if button_got_pressed():
    print('НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ')

print('Второй вызов')
if button_got_pressed():
    print('НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ')
```

Вывод:

```
Первый вызов
кнопка была нажата
Второй вызов
кнопка была нажата
НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ
```

2. Вариант с подменой ссылки на функцию после первого выполнения:

```
def button_got_pressed():
    print("кнопка была нажата")
    global button_got_pressed
    button_got_pressed = lambda: True

print('Первый вызов')
if button_got_pressed():
    print('НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ')

print('Второй вызов')
if button_got_pressed():
    print('НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ')
```

Вывод:

```
Первый вызов
кнопка была нажата
Второй вызов
НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ
```

Питон очень гибкий язык, вариантов много можно придумать.

Comment: Это будет работать, но я бы сказал, что передача состояния через дефолтное значение параметра - это антипаттерн.

Comment: @Xander Если знать, как это работает - то почему бы и нет ))  Хотя в классе хранить состояние конечно лучше, согласен

Answer (score 0):

Простой счетчик:

```
def button_got_pressed():
    print("кнопка была нажата")

count = 0
while count < 2:
    if button_got_pressed():
        count += 1

print("НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ")
```

Вывод:

```
*нажал кнопку
*нажал кнопку
НЕ НАДО НАЖИМАТЬ КНОПКУ ОПЯТЬ
```